# How to place an Image between the Toolbar and the NestedList in Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm trying to place an Image between the NestedList and its toolbar. I've tried overriding the NestedList to convert the first item in the list to an Image and customize the padding properties in the CSS. It was messy but it kind of work, however that's not quite what I want because now the Image is scrolling along with the rest of the items. I want the Image to stay there fixed and the items to scroll under it as if it was a part of the Toolbar. How can I do this?

I want to achieve something like this:

[image: View I'm Trying to Achieve]

Answer (score 0):

May be you can create your view like this:

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    config: {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                height: '', // if u want to give
                width: '' , //if u want to give
                title: 'ToolBar',
                docked: 'top'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'image',
                src: '', //path of image
                height: '', // as per your need
                width: '',// as per your need
                docked: 'top'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                itemId:'categoryList',
                id:'categoryList',
                itemHeight: 25,
                store:'',  // Your Store,
                listConfig:{
                    itemTpl:'{ }' // your list value
                },
                displayField:' ' // display field
            },
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'bottom'
                // additional code that you need for config your bottom toolbar
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: I could but how do I tell the NestedList to use the toolbar I create above?

Comment: sorry..i didn't get you clearly, will you please be more specific ?

Comment: In Sencha Touch (at least in the version 2.3 that I'm using), when I place a `nestedlist` on the view, it creates two things: a List and a ToolBar on top of it. That toolbar is used by the NestedList to display the Back button etc.

Therefore, If I use your layout, it'll create two ToolBars. One from this: `xtype: 'toolbar'` and one from this: `xtype: 'nestedlist'` 

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's obvious. In fact, I faced the same issue, but this is where you can use the power of html5 and css3. I played with some css properties to make it look like this image.[image]

Here the top toolbar contains the title and the nested list's toolbar contains the Back button.